# How to cast a column in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am taking data from hbase and converted it to dataframe. Now, I have a column in data-frame which is `string` datatype.But i need to convert its datatype to `Int`.

Tried below code but its throwing me an error

```
df.withColumn("order", 'order.cast(int)')
```

Error i am facing is below

```
error:col should be column
```

I have given proper column name here, Do i need to change the syntax of above mentioned code in pyspark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either:

```
df.withColumn("order", df.order.cast("int"))
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("order", expr("CAST(order AS INTEGER)"))
```

Comment: I get this error notebook:1: error: value cast is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame